# Given the name of a positional parameter to a function, can the parameter's position be determined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a toy Python typechecker, using the function annotation feature in Python 3 to define types for function parameters and return values, and I seem to have run into a problem in checking whether one function type is a subtype of another. Take these two functions:

```
def f(x: int, y: int) -> type(None):
    pass

def g(a: object, b: int) -> type(None):
    pass
```

I want to have my code determine that the type of `g` is a subtype of the type of `f` (since the type of each of `f`'s parameters is a subtype of the type of the parameter at the same index in `g`'s parameter list, and the return type of `g` is a subtype of the return type of `f`). However, the `__annotations__` field is a dictionary:

```
f.__annotations__ == { 'x': int, 'y': int, 'return': type(None) }
```

which means it doesn't provide me with the information about parameter ordering that I think I need. Is there a reliable way to determine that `x` is the first parameter to `f`, just from inspecting runtime properties of `f`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Python functions do carry that information.

Easiest would be to use the [`inspect.getfullargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.formatargspec) function to extract this information, or from Python 3.3 onwards, using the [`Signature` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect-signature-object).

The `inspect.getfullargspec()` return value has a `.args` attribute listing the arguments in order:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def f(x: int, y: int) -> type(None):
...     pass
... 
>>> def g(a: object, b: int) -> type(None):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(f)
FullArgSpec(args=['x', 'y'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={'x': <class 'int'>, 'y': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'NoneType'>})
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(f).args
['x', 'y']
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(g).args
['a', 'b']
```

Annotations are included too:

```
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(f).annotations
{'x': <class 'int'>, 'y': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'NoneType'>}
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(g).annotations
{'return': <class 'NoneType'>, 'a': <class 'object'>, 'b': <class 'int'>}
```

Signature objects are richer still:

```
>>> sig_f = inspect.signature(f)
>>> sig_g = inspect.signature(g)
>>> sig_f.parameters
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('x', <Parameter at 0x1031f1ea8 'x'>), ('y', <Parameter at 0x102e00228 'y'>)]))
>>> sig_f.parameters['x'].annotation
<class 'int'>
>>> sig_g.parameters['b'].annotation
<class 'int'>
>>> sig_f.return_annotation == sig_g.return_annotation
True
```

where `Signature.parameters` uses an ordered dictionary, letting you compare parameters in the correct order.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the quick response! SO won't let me accept it as correct until another 10 minutes have passed, but this totally answers my question.